# SQL replace function doesn't work

Tags: sql, t-sql

When I insert a comment i want to replace the vowels in the sentence if they are swear words.
I have a table with swear words. 
(I now have only 2 words in the table but there will be added more later)

I have a table Badwords like this:

```
Word
----------
Luke
father
----------
```

Now when I insert 'Luke, I am your father' I Want it to return ‘L-k- ,  I am your f-th-r’

This is what I’ve got. But it doesn’t replace anything.

```
CREATE TRIGGER replace_badWords ON comment
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @word AS NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @wordCursor AS CURSOR;
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(500) = (SELECT I.messageText FROM inserted I )

SET @wordCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT word FROM Badwords;
OPEN @wordCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @wordCursor INTO @word;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @text=REPLACE(@text,@word,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@word,'A','-'),'E','-'),'I','-'),'O','-'),'U','-')) 
FETCH NEXT FROM @wordCursor INTO @word;
END;
INSERT INTO Comment(messageText) values(@text)
CLOSE @wordCursor;
DEALLOCATE @wordCursor;
```

Output: Luke, I am your father

I want the output to be like this: L-k-, I am your f-th-r

Does anyone know how to fix this??

Comment: Are you sure you wish to do this *permanently* inside the database? What happens if a new bad word is added in 6 months time? You have to re-process all of your data. What happens if sensibilities change in a year and `father` becomes acceptable? You have to undo your corrupted forms (and worse, what if someone actually had entered and meant `f-th-r` - you'd actually change their original). I'd strongly advise storing the actual text the user supplied and only performing this replacement at the point of presentation - using the *then current* set of "bad words"

Comment: (Also, your trigger is broken for other reasons - `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or **multiple** rows)

Comment: You're also not parsing words out of the string. What happens to "Rodger's declamation was heartfelt" when "clam" is naughty? How do you want to handle overlapping words, e.g. if both "lug" and "beluga" are offensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do and update on the table which contains the word and set the actual string by replacing vowels from all the words in the table.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'Luke, I am your father'

DECLARE @AbusiveWords TABLE(ID INT,Word VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @AbusiveWords (ID,Word) values (1,'Luke'),(2,'father')

UPDATE @AbusiveWords
SET @String=REPLACE(@String,Word,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Word,'A','-'),'E','-'),'I','-'),'O','-'),'U','-')) 
PRINT(@string);
```

**Output:**

```
L-k- , I am your f-th-r
```

Comment: This works on the sample data provided but will replace other instances also. Consider the beluga and lug example that HABO suggested above. Add (3,'lug') to the table and change your string above to "Luke, I am your father a beluga whale". It will change beluga even though that isn't on the list of bad words.